# What should I do to write an alghorytm that edits my XML files automaticaly

Tags: java, android, database

I´m trying to make my first android App .
I mean I can really fast understand and thats why I do my last step in my first Android App . I want that some XML files would be edited automaticaly by an alghorythm . I want specially that the texview in my xml file will be edited ...

I wrote a App for events in my Collage Club and thats because it should be every two weeks be edited . The data and the name are very important and of course the room , but its most of the time the same ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:background="@color/darkgrey">

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Termine"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="173dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    >

                <Button
                        android:text="Mehr infos"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="170dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                        android:shadowDx="0"
                        android:shadowDy="0"
                        android:shadowRadius="5"/>


                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:background="@color/maincolor">

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:textColor="@color/white"
                          android:text="- 29.06.19"
                          android:textSize="24dp" />

                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:textColor="@color/white"
                          android:text="Sitzung: H-E.51"
                          android:textSize="16dp"
                          android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:textColor="@color/white"
                          android:text="Juni22, 2019"
                          android:textSize="16dp"
                          android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                          android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="270dp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="173dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    >

                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

                        />

                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:textColor="@color/white"
                          android:text="- 13.07.19"
                          android:textSize="24dp"
                        />

                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:textColor="@color/white"
                          android:text="Sitzung: H-E.51"
                          android:textSize="16dp"
                          android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

                        />
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:textColor="@color/white"
                          android:text="July13, 2019"
                          android:textSize="16dp"
                          android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                          android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"

                        />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="173dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    >

                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:background="@color/yellow"

                        />

                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:textColor="@color/white"
                          android:text="- 27.07.19"
                          android:textSize="24dp"
                        />

                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:textColor="@color/white"
                          android:text="Sitzung: H-E.51"
                          android:textSize="16dp"
                          android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

                        />
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:textColor="@color/white"
                          android:text="July27, 2019"
                          android:textSize="12dp"
                          android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                          android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"

                        />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="173dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    >

                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:background="@color/maincolor"

                        />

                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:textColor="@color/white"
                          android:text="unwichtig"
                          android:textSize="24dp"
                        />

                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:textColor="@color/white"
                          android:text="Sitzung: H-E.51"
                          android:textSize="16dp"
                          android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

                        />
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:textColor="@color/white"
                          android:text="August10, 2019"
                          android:textSize="12dp"
                          android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                          android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"

                        />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope you understand what I want to do .... That every two weeks it should be changed two another date again in 2 weeks and so on ... The name can be the same but i want to know how I need to write the code and what I should do for it ....
Thank you very much for everyone who want to help ....

It´s difficult but thats why I´m here 
Thank you

Comment: Have you had any experience writing code in java ? Did your write any java code when you created your Collage Club App ?

Comment: I mean i haven`t so much experience in Java but if you could tell what I need for this ... I can learn it . I mean maybe firebase or something like this ...

Comment: The reason I asked this is because the way you asked the question made me think that you created your previous app as a static app working around some XML in the layout file right ? I could be wrong. Coming back to your question, before I can comment any further please confirm me this. Do you know that all the tags in your XML like <TextView> are actually java classes whose objects you can get by calling findViewById() function and after that you can change there fields like textSize or text using those object which in turn will change the XML of that tag ?

Comment: If you don't know what I'm talking about, please don't hesitate to tell. I'm just trying to confirm that whether I understood what you are trying to ask correctly or not so I can guide you the best way I can. Thanks

Comment: Sure I know what you are talking about ... I mean i don`t really know how to do it ... If you could help me with the code and with the implementaion I would be really happy ...

Comment: Do you really understand what I want to do ? .. So if you don`t know then I can explain that to your in Details if you want ... Just write it here ...

Comment: What I understand is that when you first launch your app there is a list of names and dates and after every 2 weeks you want to change the date to a new date. Can you tell me where this new date will come from ? Will that new date be the system date or something else ? Check my answer for reference.

Comment: Also can you tell why do you want to change your Layout XML files ?. Because when your app is running there are no layout XML files at that time. Layout XML files convert to java classes when you build and run your project. They are only present during development. Are you talking about changing XML files during app development or during when app is running on android phone ?

Comment: So yes i think you understand it . Yeah I have 5 Cardviewvs with a button (when I click it comes detailed Information about my course. ) a TextView (where?) and I dont know maybe a timer(when the next course will be started.) . And as I already said a Date . So 2 textviews a button and a Timer .I want that every two weeks will be generate a NEW cardview and on this again the same Button but not the same Date and not the same timer ... So if I have today my course and this will be show in the first row. The second Cardview will be show with another date when the first Cardview is

Comment: 05.07.19 as a Date and the place is maybe Room 223 then the second Cardview is 2 weeks later ... so 19.07.19 and if this date of the first Cardview is reached and the time too so maybe for example 12pm then should the first Cardview be deleted and the second cardview should be at the first ... You know ? ... I hope you understand .... Yeah and I dont know what I need for this ... So Yeah i dont know ..

Comment: Your question is getting too broad. It's better that you share your project files on Github or upload them on dropbox or google drive so I can check it and we can chat via email or google hangouts to help you in the code. I'll be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this. The following code will get the system current date, display it in `TextView` and store it using [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#pref). Also upon future launches of the app, this code will calculate days between current date(the date when you will launch the app) with the date that we stored on first launch of the app. If days passed are more than 14 which means 2 weeks have been passed it will update the `TextView` to the new current date and also store it again and overwrite the previous stored date.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
DateTime currentDate;
DateTime oldDate;
String currentDateString;
String storedDateString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Get a reference to the TextView
    textView = findViewById(R.id.date_TextView);

    // DateTimeFormatter is a Jode-Time class : used for formatting date in this pattern
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

    //Getting current system date  and converting to string using the above pattern
    //DateTIme is also from Joda-Time library
    currentDate = DateTime.now();
    currentDateString = currentDate.toString(dateFormat);

    //Getting stored date string from SharedPreference
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    storedDateString = sharedPreferences.getString("dateInText","null");

    //Checking if stored date is equal to null it means this is the first launch of the app
    if (storedDateString.equals("null"))
    {
        //Storing date using SharedPreference
        SharedPreferences.Editor  editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("dateInText" , currentDateString);
        storedDateString = currentDateString;
        editor.commit();
    }
    else
    {
        //Converting stored date string into DateTime object
        oldDate = dateFormat.parseDateTime(storedDateString);

        //Calculating difference between stored date and current date
        int daysBetweenBothDates = Days.daysBetween(oldDate,currentDate).getDays();

        //If 2 weeks have been passed then update the stored date
        if(daysBetweenBothDates >= 14) {
            storedDateString = currentDateString;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("dateInText", currentDateString);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

    //Display stored date
    textView.setText(storedDateString);

  }
}
```

**NOTE:** I'm using a third party library for all date and time manipulations called [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html). You will have to include this library if you want to run this code. You can do that by going to **app\build.gradle** file and adding `implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.2'` under dependencies. Like this

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Okay bro this is insane cool : ) I mean I will upload my files on GitHub and share that with you but this is really cool .... I need a littlebit help to understand the code but that is really nice .... Thank you for that ...

Comment: Here is my GitHub file ... The file name ist : StackHelp.CoderDojo.zip Link : https://github.com/german278/CoderDojoApp